# SuperDevMode GWT 2.7.0 -noserver keeps crashing on slf4j

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, slf4j

Trying to start the codeserver for GWT 2.7.0 with the -noserver option. When I fire it up I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.warn(JettyAwareLogger.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setFailed(AbstractLifeCycle.java:204)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:74)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:140)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:128)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener$1.run(SuperDevListener.java:84)
```

It *will* start up without "-noserver" but of course that won't work for me because I need to debug the server-side code on tomcat.

I'm using the Google plugin for Eclipse. The arguments:

```
-noserver -logLevel INFO -war "${workspace_loc:/myproject}/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources" -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -codeServerPort 9997 com.foo.MyProject
```

Throwing stuff at the wall, I have included

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my project's pom file, and excluded all other slf4j artifacts.

(edit) Here is the resulting dependency tree: (too big for SO, so pasted to pastebin) http://pastebin.com/qzRZzdW9

I've tried versions from 1.5.6 up to 1.7.16 without success.

I'm completely stumped. Please let me know if I've left anything out.

Comment: I find it really strange that `-noserver` vs. not-`-noserver` makes any difference. Also, did you have a Slf4j (transitive) dependency before adding it explicitly to your POM? Does it only happen in Eclipse or also when run from Maven with `mvn gwt:run` or similar?

Comment: Yes, very very strange! So, there were slf4j dependencies. I excluded them explicitly and can confirm there is but one slf4j jar in the classpath when I got done with everything. It happens in Eclipse, and it also happens when I run mvn gwt:run-codeserver ...

Comment: Can you share the full list of dependencies? One may be bundling Slf4j, or using different Maven GAV coordinates.

Comment: Gladly! See the edits in the main post. I welcome a second set of eyes in case I missed something!

Comment: You can try passing `-verbose:class` as JVM argument to see where the class is loaded from. But honestly, with that many deps, it's high time to split client and server parts in distinct Maven modules, and some dep management hygiene (JUnit in compile scope?)

Comment: Pushing dependencies down into modules will not get rid of them. I appreciate the effort you made to address our problem and make the comments, but I feel like your admonition on our dependency hygiene seems like going a bit too far. You have no idea what this project does or how it does it. And since we've long since drank the GWT cool-aid, standing up client and server separate GWT buildables seems like even more of a mess.

Comment: The main issue here is having server-side deps on the GWT classpath, which produces conflicts (but GWT deps on server-side build classpath can possibly be just as bad, leading to hard-to-diagnose runtime failures). Separating classpaths would solve the issue, and Maven has no other way of doing it than using separate modules. You may also want to try out the maven-enforcer-plugin with [`banDuplicateClass` rule](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html) to detect other similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's suggestion to run with `-verbose:class` was a winner. The glassfish JSR303 implementation artifact I was using had its own set of built-in slf4j classes unbeknownst to me. Pretty sneaky!

Trading that out for the Hibernate validator fixed that problem.

Problem solved!